# KIvy: mapping list of vertices for using class Mash

Tags: python, kivy

I tested application with using OpenGl and always were problems with Mesh parametr fmt, which is used for mapping list vertices. At finding the solution of problem I used more simple example.  For my question here I edited original code from Kivy manual. To code is added switch between originall and mz modified variant of code.

I tested next variants of parameter fmt with these results:

1. `vertex_format`  =  `[('v_pos', 3, 'float')]` ->
    Exception: `expected byte, found str`
2. `vertex_format`  =  `[(b'v_pos', 3, 'float')]` ->
    no picture of scene on the screen
3. I don't use parameter `fmt` ->
    picture of scene has incorrect geometry

Cann You explain me using of parametr fmt? Thank You for Your interest!

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Mesh
from functools import partial
from math import cos, sin, pi


class MeshTestApp(App):

    def change_mode(self, mode, *largs):
        self.mesh.mode = mode

    def build_mesh(self):
        #switch between original and alteration code
#        switch = False   #original
        switch = True   #alteration

        """ returns a Mesh of a rough circle. """
        vertices = []
        indices = []
        step = 10
        istep = (pi * 2) / float(step) 

        # my alteration
        # mask for mapping list of vertices
        # where is problem with format? 
        vertex_format = [(b'v_pos', 2,"float")] 

        for i in range(step):
            x = 300 + cos(istep * i) * 100
            y = 300 + sin(istep * i) * 100

            if switch == False:
                # originall code
                vertices.extend([x, y, 0, 0])
            else:
                # my alteration
                vertices.extend([x, y])

            indices.append(i)

        if switch == False:
            # originall code
            return Mesh(vertices=vertices, indices=indices)
        else:
            # my alteration
            return Mesh(vertices=vertices, indices=indices, fmt = vertex_format )

    def build(self):
        wid = Widget()
        with wid.canvas:
            self.mesh = self.build_mesh()

        layout = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, None), height=50)
        for mode in ('points', 'line_strip', 'line_loop', 'lines',
                'triangle_strip', 'triangle_fan'):
            button = Button(text=mode)
            button.bind(on_release=partial(self.change_mode, mode))
            layout.add_widget(button)

        root = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        root.add_widget(wid)
        root.add_widget(layout)

        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MeshTestApp().run()
```

Comment: Hi Simeon, cann you give me some advices?

Comment: What happens if you use `b'float'` instead of just `'float'`?

Comment: Also, I think the vertex format has to match what the vertex shader expects. Since you're using Kivy's default shader (unless I missed something), you need to set the vertex format to the same as Kivy's default, which is `[(b'vPosition', 2, 'float'), (b'vTexCoords0', 2, 'float')]`.

Comment: @Hi inclement. I didn't underestand, that mask for mapping has compulsory two parts: v|Position and vTextCoords0. I used for vertices  = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2),  . . . ]  mask vertex_format = [(b'vPosition', 2, 'float'), (b'vTexCoords0', 0, 'float')] and resuld is without mistakes. This knowledges I use in other code and send you results. Thank You!

Comment: It's not that you have to pass exactly two components like this, but that what you pass has to match what the program running on the gpu (the vertex shader) expects. You can change this program, but by default Kivy always uses the same one.